# Не работает форма подписки, не приходят письма

Tags: php, post, форма

Здравствуйте, не работает форма именно на VPS, но если скопировать сайт целиком на хостинг то все прекрасно работает!
Заранее спасибо!

Сама форма HTML

```
<div class="subscription">
    <div class="close_modal cursor"></div>
    <form class="fofms" action=""><noindex>
        <h5>Подписка&nbsp;на&nbsp;рассылку!</h5>
        <h6>Подписавшись, вы будете получили наши новости на почту!</h6>
        <input class="input" name="txtname" type="text" placeholder="* Имя" required><br>
        <input class="input" name="txtphone" type="text" id="txtphone" placeholder="* Телефон" required><br>
        <input class="input" name="txtemail" type="mail" placeholder="* Электронная почта" required><br><br>
        <label style="border-bottom: 1px Dotted transparent;">
        <div style="position:absolute;top: 64px;left: 257px;"><img src="../images/konvert1.png"></div>
    <div class="checkboxtop2">
        <input class="checkbox0" type="checkbox"><div class="checkboxtop2_txt">Я не робот</div>
    </div>
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="valTrFals" class="valTrFals" value="valTrFals_disabled">
    <div class="mr_t10">
        <p style="position: absolute;margin: -45px 0 0 0px;">Нажмите я не робот!</p>            
        <input type="submit" class="button button-rounded button-flat-primary advice_botton" style="height: 30px;" value="Подписаться на рассылку" disabled="disabled" name="btnsend">
    </div>
    </noindex></form>
</div>
<div class="subscription_ok">
<div class="close_modal cursor"></div>
    <div class="windows">
        <div class="insText"><noindex>
            <p><strong>Ваша подписка оформлена.</strong>Спасибо за подписку! Теперь вы первыми узнаете об акциях с новинками от МФО и Банках!</p>
            <p>Для отмены подписки, напишите нам на почту, support@cachebank.ru с темой "отмена подписки!"</p>
            <p><div class="button button-rounded button-flat-primary advice_botton"><div class="close_modal cursor"><div class="ok2">Все понятно</div></div></div></p>
        </noindex></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Обработчик формы PHP

```
<?php
//проверяем значения полученые при проверке скриптом формы
if (trim($_POST['valTrFals'])!='valTrFals_true') {
}
else {
        $txtname = trim($_POST['txtname']);
        $txtphone = trim($_POST['txtphone']);
        $txtemail = trim($_POST['txtemail']);

        // от кого
        $fromMail = 'robot@cachebank.ru';
        $fromName = 'КЭШБАНК Подписка!';

        // Сюда введите Ваш email
        $emailTo = 'kim.hahin@gmail.com';

        $subject = 'Подписка на рассылку!';
        $subject = '=?utf-8?b?'. base64_encode($subject) .'?=';
        $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
        $headers = "From: ". $fromName ." <". $fromMail ."> \r\n";

        // тело письма
        $body = "Письмо получено с сайта www.cachebank.ru\nИмя: $txtname \nТелефон: $txtphone \nE-mail: $txtemail";
        $mail = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f'. $fromMail );
        echo 'ok';
}
?>
```

JS Формы

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    //в этой функции отслеживается изменение чекбокса "я не робот"
    $(document).on('change', '.fofms input:checkbox', function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(".fofms input[type=submit]").removeAttr('disabled');
            $('.fofms input[type=hidden].valTrFals').val('valTrFals_true');
        }
        else {
            $(".fofms input[type=submit]").attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('.fofms input[type=hidden].valTrFals').val('valTrFals_disabled');
        }
    });

    //закрытие модального окна
    $('.close_modal, .overlay').click(function (){
        $('.subscription, .subscription_ok, .overlay').css({'opacity':'0', 'visibility':'hidden'});
        $('.subscription > .fofms textarea').val('');
        //сброс всех полей формы обраной связи
        $(':input','.fofms').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
        $(".fofms input[type=submit]").attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    //показ модального окна
    $('.open_modal_subscription').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.subscription, .overlay').css({'opacity':'1', 'visibility':'visible'});
    });

    //аякс форма обратной связи
    //проверяет какой ответ был получен
    //и в зависимости от ответа
    //выводит информацию о статусе
    //отправки письма
    $(".fofms").submit(function() {
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../function/subscription.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg == 'ok') {
                    $('.subscription_ok, .overlay').css('opacity','1');
                    $('.subscription_ok, .overlay').css('visibility','visible');
                    $('.subscription').css({'opacity':'0','visibility':'hidden'});
                }
                else {
                    $('.subscription_ok .windows').html('<h5>Ошибка</h5><p>Сообщение не отправлено, убедитесь в правильности заполнение полей</p>');
                    $('.subscription_ok, .overlay').css('opacity','1');
                    $('.subscription_ok, .overlay').css('visiFbility','visible');
                    $('.subscription').css({'opacity':'0','visibility':'hidden'});
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Может на VPS не включена возможность отправки писем функцией mail()?

Comment: Честно я в vps серверах и в консоли не очень разбираюсь, буду рад если вы мне подскажите как это сделать проверить включена она или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте работает ли функция `php mail()` на сервере, если unix/linux:

```
echo "Testing" | mail -s "Test" test@example.com
```

Проверить в `php.ini` не запрещена ли функция mail:

```
disable_functions
```

Также можно так проверить:

```
if ( function_exists( 'mail' ) )
{
    echo 'mail() is available';
}
else
{
    echo 'mail() has been disabled';
}
```

Comment: в php.ini (disable_functions =)

Comment: а через ваш код
mail() is available

Comment: @limbo после изменений `php.ini` не забудьте перегрузить (restart) сервер

Comment: Я вот че в php.ini нашел, может тут проблемы?
если че у меня 25 порт открыт

[mail function]

SMTP = localhost

smtp_port = 25

sendmail_path = /usr/lib/sendmail -t -i -f

Comment: Попробуй, sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -F"Full Name" -f'emailaddress@example.com'